# in flex how to change cursor(hand cursor) when mouse over ..eg image or chart...ects

Tags: apache-flex

how to change the cursor when move over a chart in flex i have tried useHandCursor="true" but it's not working in charts.....and it should show values also....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `buttonMode` to true.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `buttonMode` to either the `true` or `userHandCursor` setting.